# Next.js is caching my server side pages. How to disable that?

Tags: caching, next.js

I have an issue I'm having trouble to investigate: I have a production compiled server at https://preprod.weally.org/ (through nginx)
I opened the port 3000 to access directly the next server (http://preprod.weally.org:3000/)

My issue is that when I log in, I'm supposed to see a different content than a non logged user. Also editing an article should show the updated article immediately to all other users.
I noticed the returned page is correct only for its first display, it then always returns the same for any browser session: (refresh occurs only when I restart the server).

After incriminating nginx of caching for hours, I realized it was Next.js that was not calling the endpoint /api/graphql, but getting its content from cache.

My next.config.js is supposed to avoid caching (you can see the build output saying **/api/graphql** is **server** side rendered)

**Note:** when I run the server in dev mode (yarn dev), everything works as expected

```
const { i18n } = require('./next-i18next.config');

module.exports = {
    i18n,
    generateEtags: false,
    compress: false,
};
```

My question is: "what is the next step in my investigation?". I'm not feeling comfortable to debug the build process of next.js

Here's the "yarn build" output:

```
Page                                    Size     First Load JS
┌ λ /                                   3.46 kB         288 kB
├   /_app                               0 B             167 kB
├ ○ /404                                195 B           167 kB
├ ○ /about (1049 ms)                    1.69 kB         169 kB
├ λ /api/auth/[...nextauth]             0 B             167 kB
├ λ /api/auth/callback/ignore-facebook  0 B             167 kB
├ λ /api/graphql                        0 B             167 kB
├ λ /api/rest/[...restEndpoint]         0 B             167 kB
├ λ /business/[businessId]/detail       10.2 kB         295 kB
├ ○ /legal/data_deletion (2485 ms)      2.06 kB         169 kB
├ ○ /legal/privacy_policy (2510 ms)     8.6 kB          176 kB
├ ○ /legal/terms (2478 ms)              14.8 kB         182 kB
├ λ /request/[issueId]/detail           608 B           285 kB
├ λ /request/[issueId]/edit             46.5 kB         284 kB
├ ○ /signin (1143 ms)                   1.94 kB         172 kB
├ ○ /signout (1111 ms)                  2.46 kB         169 kB
└ ○ /signup (1094 ms)                   1.73 kB         172 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all           167 kB
  ├ chunks/framework.3af989.js          42.6 kB
  ├ chunks/main.fa7488.js               24.5 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app.f19732.js         98.1 kB
  ├ chunks/webpack.32a7fa.js            1.72 kB
  └ css/5d6d9ddf7d6a4cfee084.css        1.56 kB

λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
●  (SSG)     automatically generated as static HTML + JSON (uses getStaticProps)
   (ISR)     incremental static regeneration (uses revalidate in getStaticProps)
```

Comment: _"I realized it was Next.js that was not refreshing its content"_ - What makes you think it's Next.js caching the pages?

Comment: After some "blind" digging, there's the possibility of nginx caching the calls to the graphql my server requests to the backend pass through nginx. I'm having trouble debugging all this mess in remote docker containers. So I'm working on a pre-preprod configuration on a VM to be able to better understand what's happening behind the curtains.

Comment: @juliomalves I remember I had some caching behavior while in development, and I thought I'll keep focusing on my tasks and get back to the issue later. So now, as described in my previous comment, I'm not sure about what is happening, I have to equip my self with the right configuration to debug in a versatile way

Comment: @juliomalves digging in the code, I found it is probably an Apollo issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69988177/apollo-is-not-requesting-graphql-in-ssr-through-next-js

Comment: @juliomalves I came back to this issue after a long pause: I'm actually sure it is next.js that is not calling the endpoint at all and getting it from cache: I installed nginx locally and I'm passing all requests through it. As long as my project is in dev mode (yarn dev), things work fine. As soon as I build the code (yarn build & start) the endpoint stops being called except for the first rendering. I don't know where to start investigating from now, it's compiler lever debugging

Comment: It goes even beyond that, since the /api/graphql endpoint url is called only once at server start, I need to restart the server to get it called again. Its cached result is returned directly by next.js, even for SSR rendering on new browser sessions. Seems it behaves like a static content but on an API call (/api/graphql is marked by the compiler as a server ressource though)

Comment: @juliomalves so I ended up finding the origin of the bug: next.js was calling apollo, and the latter was getting the results from cache (the cache being server wide). Thanks for your comments